# Argue that the matrix $A$ is orthonormal diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix 
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ -1 & 2 & 5 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then I have to argue that $A$ is orthonormal diagonalizable.

My question is: Is it sufficient to say that as $A$ is symmetric because $A = A^T$, $A$ is self-adjoint and then it follows from the spectral theorem that $A$ is orthonormal diagonalizable.

The definition in my book says that:

**Definition:** Let $L : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator and let $\mathcal{V}$ be an orthonormal basis. Then $L$ is self-adjoint if and only if the matrix representation $_\mathcal{V} [L]_ \mathcal{V}$ is symmetric.

Does this mean that also first have to prove that $\mathcal{V}$ is an orthonormal basis? I have found the eigenvectors to be $v_1 = (1,-2,1)^T$ and $v_2 = [(-1,0,1)^T,(2,1,0)^T]$? Here I see that
$$
1 \cdot (-1) + (-2) \cdot 0 + 1 \cdot 1 = 0
$$
$$
1 \cdot 2 + (-2) \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 0 = 0
$$
but
$$
-1 \cdot 2 + 0 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 0 = -2
$$
Is $\mathcal{V}$ than an orthonormal basis still?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is enough to say that $A$ is a real symmetric matrix.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Jose!